# Intersection of compact sets in Hausdorff space is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am trying to show that if $A$ and $B$ are compact in a Hausdorff space, then their intersection is compact.

The way I did it is as follows. $A$ and $B$ are compact in a Hausdorff space, so they are closed. As a consequence, their intersection (denote it by $C$) is closed. But $C$ is closed in $A$, which is compact, so $C$ is compact.

I am pretty sure this is correct, but so far compactness seems a bit tricky, so I want to ensure I get everything right.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks good! ${}$

Comment: A little detail about "$C$ is closed in $A$": $A$ and $B$ are closed in the Hausdorff space (denoted $H$), so $C = A \cap B$ is closed in $H$. In the subspace $A$, $C \cap A = C$ is closed in $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Your proof relies on Hausdorffness, and it's worth noting that this is necessary: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229792/intersection-of-finite-number-of-compact-sets-is-compact) you will find an example of a non-Hausdorff space with two compact subsets $A$, $B$ having a non compact intersection. Neither $A$ nor $B$ is closed.

Comment: To be more precise, the proof relies on the fact that compact sets are closed. There are [non-Hausdorff spaces in which all compact sets are closed](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328725/if-every-compact-set-is-closed-then-is-the-space-hausdorff), so the proof would work fine there.