# If every compact set is closed, then is the space Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

I know that in a Hausdorff space, every compact set is closed.

However, is it true that if every compact set is closed, then the space is necessarily Hausdorff?

Comment: I suspect that you meant to ask the question in the title, not the one in the body of the question.

Comment: The title and the body ask different questions.

Comment: The title and question are different.  The title asks if every compact set is also a closed set, is the space Hausdorff.  The question asks if every set is closed and compact, is it Hausdorff.  Which do you mean?

Comment: Assuming the version in the title, such a space is at least $T_1$ because points are closed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I’m answering the question in the title. Let $X$ be an uncountable set, and let $\tau$ be the [co-countable topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) on $X$. The compact sets in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ are precisely the finite sets, which are all closed, but $X$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: yeah that would be mine too, here you see that the uniqueness of limits of sequences does not imply hausdorff

Comment: @Dominic: Sequences are worthless without assuming first countability.