# Another example of a non-Hausdorff topological space in which all compact subsets are closed

Tags: general-topology

One example of a non-Hausdorff topological space in which all compact subsets are closed is the co-countable topology on an uncountable set, as demonstrated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328725/if-every-compact-set-is-closed-then-is-the-space-hausdorff).

It was claimed (as a now-deleted answer to the above question) that the *compact complement topology* on $\mathbb{R}$ was another example, but this was proven incorrect [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416595/help-show-all-compact-sets-are-closed-in-the-compact-complement-topology).

Can someone provide an additional example of a non-Hausdorff space in whihc all compact subsets are closed?

Comment: You are looking for a topological space. Can you make precise which properties this space should have and which I must not have?

Comment: The linked question has two answers; one is the space that you already have, but the other is different.