# Properties of this topology on $\Bbb X$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

For given the usual topology 
$\tau$ on $\Bbb{R}$, define the *compact complement topology* on $\mathbb{R}$ to be $$\tau'=\{A\subseteq \Bbb{R}:A^C\text{ is compact in }(\Bbb{R},\tau)\} \cup \{\emptyset \}.$$

Hausdorff : let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be disjoint open sets containing $x$ and $y$ for $x  \ne y$ then
$$G_1  \cap G_2  = \varnothing $$
$$G_1^C \cup G_2^C  =  \Bbb R$$ but $\Bbb R$ is not compact. So space is not Hausdorff.

Connectedness: Will the above also work for connectedness? Showing it's connected?

And are there any easy proof on compactness? I already saw this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272109/compactness-in-the-compact-complement-topology) but can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works for connectedness. You have essentially shown that any two non-empty open subsets (so those sets with compact complement) always intersect. A space where this holds is called *hyperconnected* (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space)) and such spaces are connected, by the definition of connectedness.

Simple fact: as compact subsets of the standard topology are closed in that topology, all open subsets of the compact complement topology are standard open too.

Compactness is not too hard: suppose $\{U_i: i \in I\}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ by non-empty open sets. Take any $U_{i_0}$ in this cover. Then $U_{i_0}^c$ is compact (in the usual topology) and the other sets of the cover are an (also standard) open cover of the complement so there is a finite subset $F \subseteq I\setminus \{i_0\}$ that covers $U_{i_0}^c$ and then $\{U_i: i \in F \cup \{i_0\}\}$ is a finite subcover of our original cover. Hence the space is compact.

Comment: Doesn't that mean just two open sets are enough for cover .  If I could I could have given two upvotes one for compactness and other for its simplicity.

Comment: @PranitaGupta no we can have a finite subcover. Try to find a cover of size 3 without a smaller subcover.

Comment: I Don't understand . Why cover of size three? If we take two open sets that cover X then we can take same subcover and cover ,and that will be finite .

Comment: @PranitaGupta you ask whether two subsets are enough for all subcovers and I claim this is not the case. Sure, there are two element covers, but also irreducible three element open covers etc. My argument just needs to show finiteness which I did.

Comment: Irreducible? What is meaning of that in topology?

Comment: @PranitaGupta it has several meanings. An irreducible cover is one where we cannot leave one out and still have a cover.