# two compact subsets whose intersection is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I need examples such that two compact subsets whose intersection is not compact.

I need your help.

Comment: I'm waiting on the computer.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229792/intersection-of-finite-number-of-compact-sets-is-compact).

Comment: Oh, thanks! My searching skill is miserable.