# Give examples of compact spaces $A,B$ such that $A\cap B$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology

If a topological space is Hausdorff then arbitrary intersection of compact sets is compact.

How to find examples of compact  subsets $A,B$ of a topological space $X$ such that $A\cap B$ is not compact

Comment: Are you assuming that $A, B$ are compact subsets of a space $C$ ?

Comment: Take a look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229792/intersection-of-finite-number-of-compact-sets-is-compact

Comment: The title says metric spaces, the body says non-Hausdorff. When did they change the definition of a metric space so they are not Hausdorff anymore?

Comment: Never. I just pointed out the *conflict* between Metric and Hausdorff and the OP edited the body, forgetting to change the title

Comment: @b00n heT: That is good news. I'm too old to learn new definitions for metric space or for Hausdorff spaces!

Comment: how old are you @AsafKaragila

Comment: *Very* old. Some would say ancient even. Others might disagree though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider two different one-point [compactifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics)) of the same non-compact space.  Each compactification will be compact, but their intersection (the original space) will not be.

For a specific example, take $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\gamma, \delta\}$ whose open sets are as follows:

- If a subset $U$ does not contain $\gamma$ or $\delta$, then $U$ is open $\iff$ it is open in $\mathbb{R}$.
- If a subset $U$ does contain either $\gamma$ or $\delta$ (or both), then $U$ is open $\iff$ it contains all of $\mathbb{R}$.

You can check that this topology is legitimate and that $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\delta\}$ and $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\gamma\}$ are both compact.  However, $\big( \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \delta \} \big) \cap \big( \mathbb{R} \cup \{\gamma\} \big) = \mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

---

**P.S.** this general idea has been very kind to me in the past, so it might be worth bearing in mind.  For instance, read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1302201/138538) about how this one-point compactification also serves as a one-point *connectification*.

Comment: what is compactification;any easy one from you

Comment: @learnmore, a compactification of a space $X$ is a topological embedding $X \hookrightarrow X'$, where $X'$ is compact.  As a simple example, $(0, 1)$ can be canonically embedded inside $[0, 1]$, and the latter is compact.  Of note, you can always add a single point to a space in such a way that the new space is compact.  See, e.g., the so-called Alexandroff one-point compactification.

Comment: The simplest of one-point compactifications I've used above, which goes as follows:  Take a space $X$ that is not compact and add a single point to it, say $\delta$.  Then in the new space $X \cup \{\delta\}$, if a subset $U$ does not contain $\delta$, then $U$ is open $\iff$ it is open in $X$.  Otherwise if $U$ contains $\delta$, then it is open $\iff$ it also contains all of $X$.  You can verify for yourself that the topology we've given $X \cup \{\delta \}$ is indeed a topology, and further that $X \cup \{\delta\}$ is compact.

Comment: i need some time

Comment: No problem @learnmore.  Math is all about struggling through things and getting yourself unstuck.

Comment: I have verified its a topology but why is it compact?

Comment: @learnmore, suppose you have an open cover of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \delta \}$.   For the cover to be a cover, we must have an open set that contains $\delta$.  What do you know about an open set that contains $\delta$?

Comment: Ohh I got it then it must contain whole of $X$ right

Comment: mhmm, it's kind of cool when you think about it.  Hope this helped!

Answer (score 13):

Let $X$ be the real line with doubled origin, i.e., $X=\mathbb R\cup\{0'\}$ where the open sets are the open sets of $\mathbb R$ as well as all sets of the form $(U\setminus\{0\})\cup\{0'\}$, where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$.
Then $[0,1]$ and $([0,1]\setminus\{0\})\cup\{0'\}$ are compact, but their intersection $(0,1]$ is not.

Comment: what is $0^{'}$?

Comment: why is $([0,1]\setminus \{0\})\cup \{0^{'}\}$ compact

Comment: can there be an easy example ;i dont get the idea

Comment: It probably helps if you think about it more than 5 minutes.

Comment: $0'$ is a new "copy" of $0$, or simply an arbitrary object $\notin\mathbb R$. You may also view $X$ as topological space that is obtained by glueing two copies of $\mathbb R$ together at all points except theirt origins