# Find a Topology where union of compact are non compact

Tags: general-topology

Is it possible find a non-Hausdoff topology where $A$ and $B$ are compact
but $A \cup B$ is non-compact?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe so.  In particular, let $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an open cover of $A \cup B$.  Notice that this is also an open cover of $A$ and $B$ by themselves.  Since $A$ and $B$ are compact, we can find two finite subsets of $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$, one of which covers $A$ and the other of which covers $B$.  See where this is going?

On the other hand, you should consider whether the *intersection* of two compact sets is necessarily compact and whether this answer depends on Hausdorff-ness.

Spoiler:

> Click [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276721/give-examples-of-compact-spaces-a-b-such-that-a-cap-b-is-not-compact/1276731#1276731) for my solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The union of two compact sets is always compact, whether Hausdorff or not.  The easy way to see this: given any open cover of $A \cup B$, the union of a finite subset that covers $A$ and a finite subset that covers $B$ is a finite set that covers $A \cup B$.