# What properties do compact sets satisfy?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a set, and $\mathcal{C}$ be a set of subsets of $X$ which contains the empty set and is closed under finite unions and infinite intersections.

Is it true that there must exist a topology on $X$ such that the compact sets of $X$ are $\mathcal{C}$? If not, what other properties does $\mathcal{C}$ need to satisfy for this to be true?

Comment: Note that compact sets need not be closed under all intersections in general. Closed sets are. Even with two compact sets this can fail.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229792/intersection-of-finite-number-of-compact-sets-is-compact