# Intersection of compact sets in a metric space is compact or not?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If we have a family of compact sets $\{K_\alpha\} $ for some metric space then what can we say about their intersection, is it compact? if not provide me a counterexample. I know this is true in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bigcap_\alpha K_\alpha$ is closed, being the intersection of closed sets. Being a closed subset of a compact metric space (one of the $K_\alpha$), it is itself compact.

Comment: Ohh! got it. Thanks, I forgot about that

Comment: Where the fact that we have a metric space is used for the last statement. Closed subsets of compact sets are compact in a metric space. In general it does not have to hold. A similar question was asked before. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229792/intersection-of-finite-number-of-compact-sets-is-compact