# Let X be a topological space and A, B $ \subset $ X compact.....

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

Let X be a topological space and A, B $ \subset $ X compact.

a) Show that A $ \cup $ B is compact.

b) Show that if X is Hausdorff, then A $\cap$ B  is compact.

c) Show that the hypothesis that X is Hausdorff cannot be omitted in the previous item.

---

My attempt

a)
Let X be a topological space and A, B $\cup$ where A and B are compact. We will claim A $\cup$ B is compact.

Let $\{O_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be an open for A $\cup$ B, so A $\cup$ B $\subset$ $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} O_{\alpha}$.

But A $\subset$ A $\cup$ B $\subset$ $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} O_{\alpha}$.

So since  A is compact, A $\subset$ $\bigcup_{i=1}^n O_{\alpha_i}$ wherer $\alpha_i \in I$

Likewise,

B $\subset$ A $\cup$ B $\subset$ $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} O_{\beta}$.

So since  B is compact, B $\subset$ $\bigcup_{j=1}^m O_{\beta_j}$, wherer $\beta_i \in I$.

therefore,  A $\cup$ B $ \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in I}^n \cup  \bigcup_{\beta \in I}^m$, ando so,  A $\cup$ B is compact.

b)
Since X is $ T_2 $ and A, B $ \subset $ X compact, we have that A and B are closed.

So, let $ U_{\alpha} $ be an open cover of A $ \cap $ B

So, we have A $ \cap $ B $ \subset \bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha} $

So, B $ \subset \bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha} \cup$ (X\A)

Since A is closed (X∖A) is open

Therefore,

$ U_{\alpha} \cup $ X∖A is an open cover of A.

Now we have that B is compact, so it follows by definition that a finite subcover, {$U_{\alpha_1}, 
U_{\alpha_2},…, U_{\alpha_n }$, X∖A} of A exists.

Therefore,

A $\cap$ B  $\subset \{U_{\alpha_1}, U_{\alpha_2},…, U_{\alpha_n}\}$ and therefore A $\cap B$ is compact.

c)
If it is not $ T_2 $ we cannot assume A, B closed and in this case the demonstration does not take place.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: I think for c) you are expected to give an example non Hausdorff space where this fails.

Comment: For point (b): $A,B \subset X$ are compact in a $T_2$ space so they are closed. This means that also $A \cap B$ is closed. In conclusion, since $A \cap B \subset A$ (or in $B$, it's the same) which is compact, you know that also $A \cap B$ is compact.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229792/intersection-of-finite-number-of-compact-sets-is-compact),  a concrete counterexample can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments for (a) and (b) are basically correct, but in places you have badly misused notation. For example, in (b) you write:

> So, let $U_\alpha$ be an open cover of $A\cap B$.
>
> So, we have $A\cap B=\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$.

If $U_\alpha$ is an open cover of $A\cap B$, as you say in the first sentence, it is a **family** of open sets. In the second sentence, however, you make it clear that $U_\alpha$ is a single member of some indexed family of open sets. Thus, your first sentence should have read something like this:

> So, let $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$ be an open cover of $A\cap B$.

Later you write:

> $U_\alpha\cup X\setminus A$ is an open cover of $A$

This says that a single set $U_\alpha\cup X\setminus A$ covers $A$. There are two problems here. First, the expression is ambiguous: should it be read $(U_\alpha\cup X)\setminus A$, or should it be read $U_\alpha\cup(X\setminus A)$? Use parentheses when there’s any real possibility of ambiguity. The real problem, though, is that you actually meant something completely different: you meant that $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}\cup\{X\setminus A\}$ is an open cover of $A$.

By the way, you can avoid indexing altogether. For (a), for instance, let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $A\cup B$. $A$ and $B$ are compact, and $\mathscr{U}$ is clearly an open cover of each of them, so there are a finite $\mathscr{U}_A\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ that covers $A$ and a finite $\mathscr{U}_B\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ that covers $B$. But then $\mathscr{U}_A\cup\mathscr{U}_B$ is a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $A\cup B$, so $A\cup B$ is compact. Similarly, in (b) you can start with an open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $A\cap B$. Then $\mathscr{U}\cup\{X\setminus A\}$ is an open cover of the compact set $B$, there is a finite $\mathscr{U}_B\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ such that $\mathscr{U}_B\cup\{X\setminus A\}$ covers $B$. $(A\cap B)\cap(X\setminus A)=\varnothing$, so $\mathscr{U}_B$ covers $A\cap B$, which is therefore compact.

Your answer for (c) is insufficient: you’ve shown that if $X$ is not Hausdorff, the argument that you gave for (b) cannot be carried out, but that does not rule out the possibility that there is some **other** argument that does not require $X$ to be Hausdorff. To answer (c), you must come up with an actual counterexample. One of the nicest is a convergent sequence with two limits:

> **Example.** Let $X=\Bbb N\cup\{p,q\}$, where $p$ and $q$ are any two points not in $\Bbb N$. Points of $\Bbb N$ are isolated. For each finite $F\subseteq\Bbb N$ let $$B(p,F)=\{p\}\cup(\Bbb N\setminus F)$$ and $$B(q,F)=\{q\}\cup(\Bbb N\setminus F)\,;$$ the sets $B(p,F)$ form a local open nbhd base at $p$, and the sets $B(q,F)$ form a local open nbhd base at $q$. Thus, a set $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if either $U\subseteq\Bbb N$, or $X\setminus U$ is finite. $X$ is a $T_1$ space and is almost Hausdorff: the only two points that do not have disjoint open nbhds are $p$ and $q$.
>
> Now let $A=X\setminus\{q\}$ and $B=X\setminus\{p\}$; I leave the easy verification that $A$ and $B$ are compact to you. $A\cap B=\Bbb N$, and clear $\big\{\{n\}:n\in\Bbb N\big\}$ is an open cover of $A\cap B$ with no finite subcover.