# Where does "A family of compact sets with the finite intersection property has nonempty intersection" lie between $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

This question is a follow-up of sorts to [a recent question by Steven Clontz](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4815055/1210477) about the property that (arbitrary) intersections of compact sets are compact (abbreviated "$IKK$" in that question).

I am interested in a stronger property ("$KIP$" defined below), and where $KIP+T_1$ lies between $T_1$ and $T_2$.

I'll give definitions and some results, then conclude with my question and attempts.

---

##### Definition.

Throughout, we say a family of sets $\mathcal F$ has the *finite intersection property ($FIP$)*  if every finite intersection $F_1\cap\dots\cap F_n$, with each $F_k\in \mathcal F$, is nonempty.

> Let $X$ be a topological space.  We say $X$ has the ***compact intersection property*** (abbreviated "$KIP$") if every family of compact subsets of $X$ with the $FIP$ has nonempty intersection.

Below, we shall often abuse grammar and say things like "$X$ is $KIP$" do indicate $X$ has the compact intersection property.

It is immediate that any space in which compact subsets are closed ("$KC$") must be $KIP$.  In particular, this holds for all Hausdorff spaces.

---

##### Consequences.

> **Lemma 1.** $KIP\implies IKK$

**Proof.**

Let $X$ be $KIP$, and suppose $\mathcal K$ is a family of compact sets.  We wish to show $\bigcap \mathcal K$ is compact.

To this end, suppose $\mathcal C$ is a family of (relatively) closed subsets of $\bigcap \mathcal K$, having the finite intersection property.  Let $\mathcal S$ be the family of all closed subsets $S\subseteq X$ such that $S\cap \bigcap\mathcal K\in \mathcal C$.  Then for any finite collections $S_1,\dots,S_n\in \mathcal S$ and $K_1,\dots,K_n\in \mathcal K$, we have $$\bigcap_{i=1}^n(K_i\cap S_i)\supseteq (S_1\cap\dots\cap S_n)\cap \bigcap \mathcal K\neq \emptyset,$$ since the latter intersection is a finite intersection of members of $\mathcal C$.  Therefore the family $\mathcal K':=\{K\cap S\mid K\in\mathcal K,S\in\mathcal S\}$ is a family of compact sets with the $FIP$, and thus by $KIP$ has nonempty intersection.  But then $$\emptyset\neq \bigcap \mathcal K'=\left(\bigcap \mathcal K\right)\cap \left(\bigcap \mathcal S\right)=\bigcap \mathcal C.$$
Thus every family of closed subsets of $\bigcap \mathcal K$ with the $FIP$ has nonempty intersection, hence $\bigcap \mathcal K$ is compact.

> **Lemma 2.** $KIP+T_1\implies US$ ("Convergent sequences have unique limits.")

**Proof.**

Suppose $X$ is $T_1$, and not $US$.  Let $x_n\in X$ be a sequence with $x_n\to x$ and $x_n\to y$, $x\neq y$.  Since $X$ is $T_1$, $x_n$ must contain infinitely many distinct members, and so we may suppose with no loss of generality that the sequence $x_n$ consists of distinct elements not equal to $x$ or $y$.  Letting $S_N=\{x_n\mid n\geq N\}\cup \{x\}$ and $T_N=\{x_n\mid n\geq N\}\cup\{y\}$, we see that $\mathcal K:=\{S_N\mid N\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{T_N\mid N\in \mathbb N\}$ is a family of compact sets with the $FIP$, yet $\bigcap \mathcal K=\emptyset$, so $X$ is not $KIP$.

---

##### Equivalent formulation.

A perhaps more tangible formulation of $KIP$ is the following:

> **Lemma 3.** $X$ is $KIP$ if and only if the following two conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. Pairwise intersections of compact subsets are compact ("$IKK_2$").
> 2. Every family of nonempty compact subsets of $X$, directed under reverse inclusion, has nonempty intersection ("Nonempty nested compact intersections”, or "$NKI$").

**Proof.**

If $X$ is $KIP$ then the first property follows from Lemma 1, and the second is immediate from the definition, since any family of nonempty subsets directed under reverse inclusion must have the $FIP$.

Conversely, if $X$ satisfies the preceding two properties, and $\mathcal K$ is a family of compact subsets of $X$ with the $FIP$, then the family $\mathcal K'$ of finite intersections of members of $\mathcal K$ is a directed system of nonempty compact sets, and so $\bigcap \mathcal K=\bigcap\mathcal K'\neq \emptyset$.

---

##### In $ZFC$.

So far, everything we have said is valid in $ZF$.  Now, even in $ZFC$, a family of nonempty sets directed under reverse inclusion need not have a cofinal chain (consider, as a counter-example, the family of cofinite subsets of any uncountable set).  Nonetheless, in $ZFC$ we may replace the directed families in Lemma 3 with well-ordered chains:

> **Lemma 4.** In $ZFC$, $X$ is $KIP$ if and only if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. Pairwise intersections of compact subsets are compact.
> 2. Every chain of nonempty compact subsets of $X$, well-ordered under reverse inclusion, has nonempty intersection.

**Proof.**

From Lemma 3, $KIP$ spaces certainly satisfy the preceding properties.  Conversely, we suppose the preceding properties are satisfied, and argue by transfinite induction that for every cardinal $\kappa$, and every family $\mathcal K$ of compact subsets of $X$, having the $FIP$, and cardinality at most $\kappa$, $\bigcap \mathcal K$ is nonempty and compact.

To see this, note the claim is true for finite cardinals.  If it is true for all cardinals $\kappa'<\kappa$, and $\mathcal K$ has cardinality $\kappa$, then let $\lambda\mapsto K_\lambda$ be a bijection $\kappa\to \mathcal K$, and for each $\lambda<\kappa$ define $J_\lambda:=\bigcap_{\alpha\leq \lambda}K_\alpha$.  Then by inductive assumption  $\{J_\lambda\}$ is a well-ordered chain of nonempty compact subsets, so by the second property $\bigcap \mathcal K=\bigcap_{\lambda<\kappa} J_\lambda\neq \emptyset$.

Moreover, if $\mathcal C$ is a family of closed subsets of $\bigcap \mathcal K$ with the $FIP$, then as in the proof of Lemma 1, we let $\mathcal S$ be the family of all closed subsets $S\subseteq X$ such that $S\cap \bigcap \mathcal K\in \mathcal C$.  Then for each $\lambda<\kappa$, and any finite collection $S_1,\dots,S_n\in\mathcal S$, we have $$S_1\cap\dots\cap S_n\cap J_\lambda\supseteq S_1\cap\dots \cap S_n\cap \bigcap \mathcal K\neq \emptyset,$$ so the family $\mathcal S_\lambda:=\{S\cap J_\lambda\mid S\in \mathcal S\}$ has the finite intersection property.  Since $J_\lambda$ is compact, we have $J_\lambda\cap \bigcap \mathcal S=\bigcap \mathcal S_\lambda\neq \emptyset$.  Therefore $\{J_\lambda\cap \bigcap \mathcal S\}$ is a well ordered chain of nonempty compact sets under reverse inclusion, and so $$\bigcap \mathcal C=\left(\bigcap \mathcal S\right)\cap \left(\bigcap \mathcal K\right)= \left(\bigcap \mathcal S\right)\cap \left(\bigcap_{\lambda<\kappa} J_\lambda \right)\neq \emptyset.$$
Since this holds for any family $\mathcal C$ of closed subsets of $\bigcap \mathcal K$ satisfying the $FIP$, $\bigcap \mathcal K$ is compact.

---

## Question.

In general, $KIP$ spaces need not be $T_1$, and in fact it is easy to see that every finite topological space is $KIP$.  Moreover, even in a $T_1$ space, the properties $IKK_2$ and $NKI$ from Lemma 3 are insufficient, separately, to guarantee $US$:  If only $T_1$ and $IKK_2$ are assumed (or even $IKK$ itself), then the [cofinite topology on an infinite set](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000015) will give an example that is not $US$.    If only $T_1$ and $NKI$ are assumed, $[0,\omega]$ with a doubled endpoint gives an example that fails $US$.

Therefore it seems $KIP+T_1$ spaces may be reasonable objects of study.  Where does this property fall among other properties between $T_1$ and $T_2$?  Particularly, those discussed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4761212/1210477)?

---

##### Attempts.

We know that $KC\implies KIP+T_1\implies US$.  Moreover, the second implication is strict, as can be seen by the example of $[0,\omega_1]$ [with a doubled endpoint](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000037), which is $US$, but fails $IKK_2$, hence fails $KI$.

I suspect the first implication is strict as well (it in fact is, see update), with a possible example in $X=\mathbb Q^*\times\mathbb Q^*$, the [square of the one-point compactification of the rationals](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000031).  $X$ is not $KC$ (the diagonal being compact and not closed), but $X$ is $NKI$ (this follows from the fact that $\mathbb Q^*$ is $KC$, hence $KIP$, hence $NKI$, and it is relatively straightforward to show that a product of two $T_1$ $NKI$ spaces is again $NKI$).

However, I ran into trouble trying to determine whether $X$ is $IKK_2$.  I expect there should be either a straightforward proof of this, or a straightforward counter-example, but both have so far eluded me.

---

##### Update.

I neglected to consider the [one point compactification of the Arens-Fort space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000165/properties), discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/435257/513553).  Subsets there are compact if and only if they are either finite, or contain the point at infinity.  From this, $KIP$ is immediate, yet this space is not $KC$ or even [weak Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000143), though it is [$k_2$-Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000171).

Given that the implication $KC\implies KIP+T_1$ is indeed strict, it remains to show how $KIP+T_1$ relates to the aforementioned properties (i.e., does weak Hausdorff imply $KIP$, and is there an implication in either direction for $k_2$-Hausdorff?) or any other weak separation axioms.

---

##### Addendum.

Let me add one additional set of observations that I didn't mention originally.  They weren't particularly fruitful for me, but might be of some use that I didn't see:

If $X=(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, let $\tau_{cc}\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ consist of the co-compact subsets of $X$, together with the empty set.  Then

> 1. $\tau_{cc}$ is a topology if and only if $X$ is $IKK$.  In this case $\tau_{cc}$ is always $T_1$.
> 2. $\tau_{cc}$ is a compact topology if and only if $X$ is $KIP$.
> 3. $\tau_{cc}\subseteq \tau$ if and only if $X$ is $KC$.
> 4. $\tau_{cc}\supseteq \tau$ if and only if $X$ is compact.

Comment: Interesting stuff.  One trivial comment: naming it KIP instead of KI would be more mnemonic to me, reminds one of FIP.

Comment: @PatrickR I thought about that, but I didn't like having it seem too symmetric with FIP, since KI doesn't simply replace "finite" with "compact" in the FIP... of course, by that reasoning I should not have named this the "compact intersection property" either, though I couldn't come up with anything better.  I'm not in love with the nomenclature I used though, might adjust at some point.

Comment: In the end, I think you were right about notation, going with $KIP$.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, but it may be of some use in determining separation properties on $\pi$-base so I've decided to post it.

We actually have

> **Proposition 1.** $KIP+T_1\implies k_2\text{-Hausdorff}$.

---

**Proof.**

The proof is similar in spirit to the proof for $KIP+T_1\implies US$, and could be thought of as a generalization, though we will argue more directly this time.  Suppose $X=X$ is $T_1$ and $KIP$.  Let $f,g\colon Z\to X$ be continuous maps from a compact Hausdorff space $Z=(Z,\tau)$ into $X$, and let $A=\{a\in Z\mid f(a)=g(a)\}$.  We argue that $A$ is closed.

To see this, suppose $z\in \overline{A}$.  Let $\mathcal K_f=\{f(\overline{U})\mid z\in U\in \tau\}$, define $\mathcal K_g$ similarly, and let $\mathcal K=\mathcal K_f\cup \mathcal K_g$.  Then for any sets $f(\overline{U_1}), \dots, f(\overline{U_m}), g(\overline{V_1}), \dots, g(\overline{V_n}) \in \mathcal K$, we have some $a\in A\cap U_1\cap\dots\cap U_m\cap V_1\cap\dots\cap V_n$, (since $U_1\cap\dots\cap U_m\cap V_1\cap\dots\cap V_n$ is a neighborhood of $z\in\overline{A}$).  Therefore $f(a)=g(a)\in f(\overline{U_1})\cap\dots\cap f(\overline{U_m})\cap g(\overline{V_1})\cap \dots\cap g(\overline{V_n})$, so $\mathcal K$ has the finite intersection property.

By $KIP$, there is some $x\in \bigcap \mathcal K$.  We claim we must have $f(z)=x$. Otherwise, as $X$ is $T_1$, we could take a neighborhood $W$ of $f(z)$ avoiding $x$, and by regularity of $Z$ choose a neighborhood $U$ of $z$ with $\overline{U}\subseteq f^{-1}(W)$, obtaining a contradiction with $$x\notin f(\overline{U})\supseteq \bigcap \mathcal K\ni x.$$

Similarly, we have $g(z)=x$, so that $f(z)=g(z)$, whereby $z\in A$.  Thus $A$ is closed, and since this holds for arbitrary pairs of maps into $X$, the diagonal is $k_2$-closed.  Thus $X$ is $k_2$-Hausdorff.

---

##### Remarks.

We now have $$KC\implies KIP+T_1\implies k_2\text{-Hausdorff}.\tag{1}$$  From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4760309/how-are-k-hausdorff-and-weakly-hausdorff-distinct?noredirect=1&lq=1) we also know $$KC\implies \text{weak Hausdorff} \implies k_2\text{-Hausdorff},\tag{2}$$ and from the example of the one point compactification of the Arens-Fort space in the question above, we know that a space can be $KIP$ without being weak Hausdorff.  Therefore three possibilities remain:

1. There is a weak Hausdorff space (which a fortiori is also $k_2\text{-Hausdorff}$) that fails to be $KIP+T_1$, so that the implications in (1) and (2) are strict, and neither weak-Hausdorff nor $KIP+T_1$ imply the other.
2. We have $\text{Weak Hausdorff} \implies KIP+T_1\implies  k_2\text{-Hausdorff}$, with all implications strict.
3. We have $KIP+T_1\iff k_2\text{-Hausdorff}$

My suspicion is that 1 is most likely, but either 2 or 3 would be quite interesting.

In any case, if $X$ is assumed to be compactly generated [($CG_2$)](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000141), we know from the answers to the linked question that the three properties in (1) are equivalent, hence from the proposition we see that they are all equivalent to $KIP+T_1$.  Thus we have another characterization of $CGWH$ spaces as those $CG_2$ spaces which are $T_1$ and satisfy $KIP$.  Or, if a stronger version of compactly generated is used [($CG_3$)](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000142), we may drop the $T_1$ assumption as it is built into $CG_3$.

---

##### Application.

We also have the following useful application of the above proposition:

> **Proposition 2.**  Let $X$ be countable and $US$.  Then $X$ is $KIP$, hence $k_2\text{-Hausdorff}$.

**Proof**.  Let $X$ be countable and $US$.  From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4851117/1210477) we know that in countable spaces, compactness and sequential compactness coincide.  If $K\subseteq X$ is compact, and $x_i\to x\in X$ with each $x_i\in K$, then by sequential compactness, there is a subsequence of $(x_i)$ converging to some $k\in K$, and by $US$, we must have $x=k$.  We conclude that compact subsets are sequentially closed.  On the other hand, a sequentially closed subset of a (sequentially) compact space is certainly again sequentially compact, so the intersection of any family of compact sets must be compact, i.e., $X$ satisfies condition $IKK$ (and a fortiori $IKK_2$) from the above question.

On the other hand, if $(K_\alpha)$ is a (strictly) decreasing transfinite sequence of non-empty compact subsets of $X$, then by countability of $X$, $(K_\alpha)$ is countable, so after passing to a cofinal chain if necessary, we may re-index the chain by naturals $(K_n)$.  Then choosing $x_n\in K_n$, we have some convergent subsequence $y_m\to y$.  By sequential closure of compact sets, we must have $y\in \bigcap_n K_n$, so $\bigcap_n K_n\neq \emptyset$.  Thus $X$ satisfies the nonempty nested intersection property $NKI$, alongside $IKK_2$, which is an equivalent formulation to $KIP$ as proved in the question above.

---

It is worth noting that in the question above, it was not clear whether $\mathbb Q^*\times \mathbb Q^*$ was $KIP$.  As a corollary to Proposition 2, we see that it is, though in this example, since $\mathbb Q^*\times\mathbb Q^*$ was already known to be weak Hausdorff, concluding it is $k_2\text{-Hausdorff}$ from Proposition 1 yields nothing new.

---

I will leave this question open for now, in the hopes that someone can determine what the precise status of $KIP+T_1$ is, in terms of the three possibilities mentioned above.